# show using probability axioms $P[A\bigcap B] \ge P[A] + P[B] - 1$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

show using probability axioms $P[A\bigcap B] \ge P[A + P[B] - 1$

I used the axiom $PA + P[B] - P[A\bigcap B] = P[A \bigcup B]$

$P[A \bigcap B] = P[A] + P[B] - P[A \bigcup B] $

So $PA + P[B] - P[A \bigcup B] \ge P[A] + P[B] -1 $

$-P[A \bigcup B] \ge -1 $

$P[A \bigcup B] \le 1 $

Using the axiom $P[A] + P[B] - P[A\bigcap B] = P[A \bigcup B]$ again:

$P[A] + P[B] - P[A \bigcap B] \le 1$

$P[A] + P[B] - 1 \le P[A \bigcap B] $ which is eqivalent to  original

Is this a valid approach? I used the same axiom twice..

I'm new to this so apologies if this is some obvious mistake..

Comment: $P[A \bigcup B] \le 1$, at this moment work already done

Comment: From your first step, simply note $P(A \cup B) \le 1$ (probabilities must be $\le 1$).

Answer (score 1):

$A = (A \cap B) \cup (A \setminus B)$

$B = (A \cap B) \cup (B \setminus A)$

$p A + p B = 2 p (A \cap B) + p (A \setminus B) + p (B \setminus A)  = p (A \cap B) + p (A \cup B) \le p (A \cap B) + 1$.

Comment: how did you get from the 2nd to the third equality?

Comment: $A \cup B = A\setminus B \cup (A \cap B) \cup B \setminus A$, and this is a disjoint partition.